# button disappear in HTML after clicking

Tags: html, button

Pressing button will disappear, and the next button appears in HTML-
I want to create 5 buttons When the first button in a specific location. Only after the user clicks on the first button, then the user will see the second button which is in a different location.The same applies to all the buttons.

I RUN IT HERE:

http://bit.ly/1lkoLSK

another problem that the code run only on firefox-why ?

Comment: Include your relevant code in the question itself. Links can become obsolete.

Comment: Seems to work for me in Chromium, you will need Jquery or JS to have one disappear after clicking and have another appear in a different place. But yes, please post you code.

Comment: but how I add posiotions after 2 clicks ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understand your problem correctly, but show first button, than on click just hide current active element and show next one. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/H3R8x/2/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next.show();
});
```